# Map over an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

I have this json file in a react app. 
How can I display the content of the array [emails] ?

```
{
  "deputes" : [ {
    "depute" : {
      "emails" : [ {
        "email" : "email1@email.fr"
      }, {
        "email" : "email2@email.fr"
      } ],
```

Right now, I can use this code to display the first item

```
<Text>{emails[0].email}</Text>
```

and [1] for the second. 
But how can I show all of them with .map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map through the emails array.

```
emails.map(e => <Text>{e.email}</Text>)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like that :

```
emails.map(email => <Text>email.email</Text>)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rodius and @benjaminRampon! Could make it work!